# how to append radiobutton value to list

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests

I making an OMR card program.
but I have a problem.
I can not append radiobutton's value to list.
I want to make user's answer list and compare with a real answer, but I can not make user's answer list.
I think check function is the problem.
Please help me

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
win = Tk()
win.title("Exam")
win.geometry('1530x300+0+690')

def problem1():
    for i in range(0,10):
        i += 1
        label = Label(win, text='%d.' % i)
        label.grid(column=0, row=i)
        radVar = IntVar()
        r1 = ttk.Radiobutton(win, text="num1", variable=radVar, value=1, command = check)
        r1.grid(column=1, row=i)
        r2 = ttk.Radiobutton(win, text="num2", variable=radVar, value=2, command = check)
        r2.grid(column=2, row=i)
        r3 = ttk.Radiobutton(win, text="num3", variable=radVar, value=3, command = check)
        r3.grid(column=3, row=i)
        r4 = ttk.Radiobutton(win, text="num4", variable=radVar, value=4, command = check)
        r4.grid(column=4, row=i)

def check():
    if radVar.get() == 1 :
        list.append(1)
    elif radVar.get() == 2 :
        list.append(2)
    elif radVar.get() == 3 :
        list.append(3)
    elif radVar.get() == 4 :
        list.append(4)

radVar = IntVar()
list=[]
problem1()
action = ttk.Button(win, text = "check the answer",command = check)
action.grid(column=0, row=11)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation here is my final solution. I've used the *Python* in-built `enumerate` function to loop through the questions whilst also using a count to more efficiently and dynamically create new Radiobuttons.  This way we append answers to the list as they are selected and we can still use your `check the answer` button to review all submitted answers.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def problem1():
    for i in range(1,5):
        label = Label(win, text='%d.' % i)
        label.grid(column=0, row=i)
    for count, question in enumerate(questions, 1):
        radVar = IntVar()
        for i in range(1,5):
            button = ttk.Radiobutton(win, text="num%d" % i, variable=radVar, value=i, command=check)
            button.grid(row=count, column=i)
        answers.append(radVar)

def check():
    # check submitted answers against correct answers here
    for x in answers:
        print(x.get())

win = Tk()
win.title("Exam")
win.geometry('1530x300+0+690')
questions = ["num1", "num2", "num3", "num4"]
answers = []
problem1()
action = ttk.Button(win, text="check the answer", command = check)
action.grid(column=0, row=5)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks. i got what you mean. but i think it still have a problem. if i change ttk.Button(win,text = 'check the answer', command = check) TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'

Comment: and when i write i in ()       action = ttk.Button(win, text = "check the answer",command = check(i))
NameError: name 'i' is not defined  i have no idea...

Comment: i am not good at python so i can not understand about your answer. you mean that pasted your code in my code right? but still get error         |  Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\max99\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'       |    what is my problem?

Comment: so thank you about your answer. i have a question. if i want to make 100 problems what should i change?

Comment: easy you'd just increase the `for` loop maximum values to `for i in range(1,101)`. p.s. if you find any answers to your questions helpful then please consider accepting/upvoting